# Get segment of string without specific suffix with JS regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a url, it can either be

```
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934
```

or with a suffix v[0-9]

```
https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934v3
```

I want to filtered out the v[0-9] part with regex.

That is, getting 'https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934', no matter which type of url us given.

Below is what I have for now, it works but seems hacky...

```
let url = 'https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934v3'
let regURL = /(.*(?<!v[0-9])(?<!v))/g;
let url_f = regURL.exec(url)[0];
```

Is there a better regex pattern for this?

Comment: Remove it first, `url.replace(/v\d+$/, '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
/^(.*?)(v\d+)?$/
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/quRVSn/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    v                        'v'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \2 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \2)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

JavaScript:

```js
let url = 'https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.10934v3'
let regURL = /^(.*?)(v\d+)?$/;
let [_, url_f, version] = regURL.exec(url);
console.log(url_f);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you replace v[0-9] with empty string you will it filtered out:

```
url.replace(/v[0-9]$/, '')
```